# How to extract Data from one Cell in Excel, analyze it and then based on the outcome insert data on another

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-365

I am now learning Excel and I have an assignment which will require me to write some VBA since I cannot work my way around it with functions this time.

I have written quite the complicated functions before in C# so I have a pretty good understanding of coding. This time though I have no idea how to approach this.

My assignment is the following.

We have 2 sheets in the same Excel document, on sheet No.1 we have a table with the amount (int) of calls that we received from every single US State (e.g. California 19, Nevada 12 etc.)per month, and on sheet No.2 we have the input of the user that is logging the calls.
Now on sheet No.2 we have come to an agreement that the user will populate Column H for example starting with the State abriviation (e.g.CA, (Serial No. of device), (Issue found)) and I will have to extract that abriviation, compare it with my table of abriviations (in VBA I guess) and then have the program go to sheet No. 1 and add +1 to the summary of calls of California.

Thank you for you time reading this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried using Funtions like LEFT(text, [num_chars]) but I have to analize the data somehow.

Edit: Submitting two pictures of sheet No.1 & No 2. respectively.
The code should run whenever the cell on sheet No.2 value changes.

[Sheet No.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae8CY.png)
[Sheet No.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmESa.png)

Comment: When sould this code run? Everytime a button is hit? Everytime a specific cell's value changes? Something else?

Comment: How is the table in sheet 1 formatted? It would be helpful to edit the question and add some sample data of the table in sheet 1. It is important to know where to search. You are not so specific.

Comment: What have you tried so far? See "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)